# Styles injection order with JSS and Material-UI differs between dev and prod

Tags: material-ui, next.js, jss

I'm trying to use Material-UI (https://material-ui.com/) with NextJS (https://nextjs.org/), styling with the JSS solution.

**It works well in my local environment, but my design is broken on prod**. After a quick analysis, it seems to be an **issue with the injection order** of the `<style>` tag: my styles are indeed injecting between MUI ones, canceling my changes.

**DEV ENVIRONMENT**
[image: In dev]

**PROD ENVIRONMENT**
[image: In prod]

As you can see from the screenshots above, the injection order is different in prod. The `Alert` style is therefore overwritten by the `MuiButton` making my page broken.
*(I also don't get why the styles for `Alert` and `DashboardLayout` have an empty clone, but that's not my main issue here...)*

It may be worth to note that the **styles generated on the server-side are OK**: the page is rendered correctly on loading. The issue occurs only after the client-side has run.

My code is based on [this example from Material-UI (usage with NextJS)](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/examples/nextjs/).

I really don't get why it's OK on dev and not on prod (and **I don't manage with NextJS to run the prod build on local for an easier debugging ^^'**).

Do you have an idea on how to understand and investigate this issue?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I've asked the question also on [the Material-UI repo](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/21323), and the maintainer provides me some useful information.

The main point I've missed it that `<styles>` are injected when `makeStyles` is called: **injection order is the same than calls to `makeStyles` order**.

The file defining my `Alert` component was including before `Button` component, that's why its style was injecting before the one for `Button`. **It breaks my design, but it's logical and this behavior is intended**.

The fact that it works on dev environment is a mystery on my side... But it's a buggy behavior, so we have to be cautious!

In order to solve my issue, I've just need to be sure that the calls order of `makeStyles` was the intented one.